# Dynamics Custom Action Process Session

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrm

I am working with a test action that when activated and called via javascript will fire an email message.  I used an action because I wanted to pass in some values to be used in the process.  In a traditional workflow I could see the history of each time the workflow was fired.

Is there a way to see all of the times my custom action fired?

Comment: If your action is backed up by plug-in, you’ll see it in plug-in trace logs. Also you can put in step to create some auditing entity. Btw. as far as I know you can specify parameters even for async workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional workflow are Asynchronous. What you are seeing as Process Sessions are actually Async Execution logs. Those are not available/applicable for Sync jobs like Realtime workflows or Actions. Maybe you can keep the failure logs in Action.

Unfortunately you have to assume from the Emails that sent out is Action execution time.

[image]